# Reinitialise MembershipProvider ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, membership-provider, activedirectorymembership

I have an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and I have a SQLMembershipProvider (Essentially, its an ASP.Net app where users generated for the application and users from the active directory can both login). I would like to set up the login controller so that if the AD-Provider cannot talk to the AD server when a local user logs in, it will re-initialise the ADProvider when another user tries to login.

As far as I can tell, the application initialises both providers when either one is called. the ADProvider tries to connect and if it can't it throws an error.
I currently catch the error and silently discard. Local users can log in, but when I restart my AD server, I cant seem to find a way to get the ADProvider to try and reconnect. I have tried to call initialize() again, but it throws an 'already initialized' error.

If I need to create my own, fine, I am hoping that there is some config or simple method that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out what to do in this case:

```
    //create our own AD Provider
    private System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider base_provider;

    private bool initialised = false;

    //these values are saved when Init if first called by the Membership Collection. 
    //So that I can pass them back into the new base_provider when it is made.
    private string name = null;
    private System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config;
    private Exception init_exception;

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.config = config;

        try
        {
            base_provider = new System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider();

            base_provider.Initialize(name, config);
            initialised = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.base_provider = null;
            init_exception = e;
        }
    }

    public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        if (!initialised) this.Initialize(this.name, this.config);

        //just a custom exception that my Membership object (that handles calling the two providers) picks up on
        if (base_provider == null) throw new NotInitialisedException(this.init_exception.Message);

        return base_provider.GetAllUsers(pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);
    }

    ....
```

Then for any method I dont want to implement (for instance, I don't want to change any data on the AD server, just want to list and verify users) I just have a NotImplementedException